# OpenSSL - SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb

Tags: c++, openssl

I'm needing to write a simple SSL client application to query the Amazon Web Service from C++.  It's going to be used in multi-threaded applications.

This is the first time I've ever looked at using OpenSSL and I'm needing to extend some of our our libraries to support SSL sockets.

My question is: What is the purpose of the [SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb](http://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb.html) function in OpenSSL?

In reading the man page it's not particularly clear what it does exactly.  As suggested function from the man page is this.

```
int pem_passwd_cb(char *buf, int size, int rwflag, void *password)
{
    strncpy(buf, (char *)(password), size);
    buf[size - 1] = '\0';
    return(strlen(buf));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20111003031234/http://www.rtfm.com/openssl-examples/part1.pdf), This callback is called when a password is required to decrypt an encrypted private key

Comment: A private key is needed if you're implementing the server side of an SSL connection, and on the client side iff you're using a client certificate.

Comment: I see that if you don't call that function, it requests you for a password.